Convergence of $\sin\left(\frac{S}{\sin\left(\frac{S}{\sin(\cdots)}\right)}\right)$
I was framing a question about the number of solutions of the following function defined in $\mathbb R^+$ with $y=\frac{\pi}{4x}$:
$$f(x)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sin^{-1}x+x^{2n}\tan^{-1}(x-1)}{x(1+x^{2n})}$$
$$\implies f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{\sin^{-1}x}{x}& x\in (0,1) \\ \dfrac{\pi}{4}& x=1\\ \dfrac{\tan^{-1}(x-1)}{x}& x\in (1, \infty)
\end{cases}$$
The solutions are $x=\frac1{\sqrt2}, 1, 2$ by considering each of the $3$ cases.
Since the question seemed way too simple, I decided to write $\frac{\pi}4$ as an infinite series:
$$\frac{\pi}4=\left(1-\frac1{5}+\frac1{7}-\frac1{11}+\frac1{13}+\ldots\right)\frac{\sqrt3}{2}=\frac{\sqrt3S}{2}$$
since $S=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt3}$. Then I also decided to rewrite $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ as an infinite sine composition involving the series $S$:
$$\frac{\sqrt3}{2}=\sin\left(\frac{S}{\sin\left(\frac{S}{\sin(\ldots)}\right)}\right)$$
I don’t know how to determine the convergence or divergence of  an infinitely composed function or an infinite series other than geometric series since it is not in my course. So, I wanted to know for what values of $S$ does the infinite sine composition converge? Is writing $\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ as an infinite sine composition correct? Any help would be highly appreciated.

where did you get this question

@RicciTen , my teacher asked me to frame a question on definite integration, so I thought of this function. To make the question a paragraph comprehension, I decided to add a second part which I have mentioned in this post.

The range of Sine is $[-1,1]$ and $\sin([-1,1])$ is contracting. Ofcourse what you ask is not just an iteration of sines. I need to think ...

No real value for $S$ seems to work.  By iterations you end up with $arcsin(t)$ for $t>1$.

@mick , how did you come to that conclusion? Please explain.

Those who have any doubts or require any clarification, kindly comment before downvoting without any explanation.

@mick Anyways, in real analysis, $\arcsin(t)$ is not even defined for $t>1$!

I fail to see the connection to the 3 things you describe ?

@mick I mean that you have mentioned that with iterations, we get $\arcsin t$ for $t>1$ but that is not a real number.

@RakshithPL I meant in the OP

@Mick can you please tell me which 3 things are you referring to? The basic goal is to write $\frac{\pi}4=S\sin\left(\frac{S}{\sin\left(\frac{S}{\sin(\ldots)}\right)}\right)$ and I asked whether it is meaningful or not.

Well you had a limit , a sum and then an iteration. It is not clear how they relate, at least to me. @RakshithPL

@mick In the question I was framing about a function defined in the form of a limit, I got motivated to write $\frac{\pi}4$ as an infinite series(since the question would have been very straightforward if I simply wrote find the no. of solutions of $xf(x)=\frac{\pi}4$). Then since anyone could easily evaluate the value of this series, I decided to manipulate it further by writing it as an iteration.

@MathGuy ah ok. And the edited answer also made things more clear. I got issues because I thought it was about universal convergeance but there is a domain

To justify the equality involving $S$ we have to provide its correct interpretation.
For this purpose we introduce the sequence $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $S_1=\sin S$ and $S_{n+1}=\sin\frac {S}{S_n}$ for each natural $\ge 1$ and look for its limit $L$, if it
exists. If $L\ne 0$ then $L$ is a fixed point of a function $f(x)=\sin\frac{S}x$, that is $f(L)=L$. The graph of the function $f(x)$ suggests that the function $f(x)$ has a lot of fixed points.

The sequence $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $L$ if $S_n=L$ for some natural $n$. But such exact hit looks improbably. More probable scenario is that $L$ is an attracting fixed point and $S_n$ belongs to the basin of attraction of $L$ for some natural $n$. The point $L$ is attracting, if $|f'(L)|<1$ and repelling if $|f'(L)|>1$, by the definition of a derivative. But
$$|f'(L)|=\left|\frac{S}{L^2}\cdot \cos\frac S{L}\right|=S\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1-L^2}}{L^2}.$$
Then $L$ is an attracting fixed point if $|f'(L)|<1$ that is if
$$S\cdot \frac{\sqrt{1-L^2}}{L^2}<1$$
$$S^2(1-L^2)<L^4$$
$$L^4+S^2L^2-S^2>0$$
Solving the respective quadratic equation, we obtain
$$|L|>\sqrt{\frac S2(\sqrt{S^2+4}-S)}=0.7645\dots.$$
The computer calculation suggests that the sequence $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $L=\frac{\sqrt{3}}2=0.8660\dots$, which is an attracting fixed point. The Lagrange theorem implies that
an interval $[a,b]\ni L$ belongs to the basin of attraction of $L$ provided there exists a positive $M<1$ such that $|f'(x)|\le M$ for each $x\in [a,b]$. This holds, for instance, when $a=\frac 34$ and $b=1$, because then $$\left|\frac{S}{x^2}\cdot \cos\frac S{x}\right|\le \frac{S}{\left(\frac 34\right)^2\cos S}=0.9934\dots.$$
Since $S_2=\sin\frac S{\sin S}=0.9133...\in [a,b]$, the sequence $(S_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ indeed converges to $L$.

Is it possible to conclude that the sequence diverges theoretically?

I must be missing something, but I don't get it. For $S=0.9068996821$ I get $S_1 =0.7875971415$ , $S_2 = 0.9133661193$, and it tends to $\sqrt{3}/2$

@leonbloy Oops, I also checked my program and found that I used the wrong value of $S$.
Now I agree with you. Sorry for the error and thanks for the attention.

@AlexRavsky I think the $\left|\frac{S}{L}\cos\left(\frac{S}{L}\right)\right|$ should be $\left|\frac{S}{L^2}\cos\left(\frac{S}{L}\right)\right|$.

And can you please explain how you wrote $L$ in terms of $S$ in the line of 0.76...?

@RakshithPL Thanks for your attention and sorry for the misprint. I fixed it. Also I extended the relevant fragment of the answer.

Thanks for clarifying that part. Further, I wanted to ask, what is the value of $S$?

@RakshithPL The value $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt3}$ of $S$ I took from your question.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@AlexRavsky In the last few lines, what does positive integer $M<1$ mean?
